# How do I access X-Forwarded-For header for Spring Boot app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

I have the following to print out all the request headers. It is not printing out `X-Forwarded-For` header. The documentation states that Elastic Beanstalk *does* forward the real IP of the client.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html

```
private method(@RequestHeader final HttpHeaders headers) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    headers.forEach((h, v) -> {
        sb.append(h);
        sb.append(v);
        System.out.println(h+": "+v);
    });
```

When I view the AWS logs for the environment, I see `x-forwarded-proto` and `x-forwarded-port` but not `x-forwarded-for`. Why?

```
connection: [upgrade]
host: [dev.example.com]
x-real-ip: [172.99.99.999]
x-forwarded-proto: [https]
accept: [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3]
accept-encoding: [gzip, deflate, br]
accept-language: [en-US,en;q=0.9]
cache-control: [no-cache]
cookie: [_ga=GA1.2.9999999.999999999; JSESSIONID=99AAA9999A999A99999AAAAA99999AAA999; AWSELB=99999AAA9999AAAA99999AAAA]
pragma: [no-cache]
sec-fetch-mode: [navigate]
sec-fetch-site: [none]
sec-fetch-user: [?1]
upgrade-insecure-requests: [1]
user-agent: [Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Mobile Safari/537.36]
x-forwarded-port: [443]
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199872/discussion-between-chloe-and-juned-ahsan).

Comment: I was able to access the IP with `String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();` but it doesn't make sense because that is supposed to be the proxy's address. `Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request. For HTTP servlets, same as the value of the CGI variable REMOTE_ADDR.` I printed the value and verified it was the correct IP, but I don't know how it works. It will likely break in a different version of Spring Boot.